# Mysql Execute two query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How do I execute the following code in wordpress

```
Set time_zone = '+07:00';
SELECT current_date
```

I tried the following but I didn't get any result.

```
$sql = 'Set time_zone = '+07:00';
        SELECT current_date'; 
$wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

I run the query in phpmyadmin and its working but why it doesn't work in wordpress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to execute the query one by one.

```
$sql = "Set time_zone = '+07:00'";
$wpdb->get_var($sql); 
$sql = "SELECT current_date"; 
$wpdb->get_var($sql);
```